# IQueryable Multiple Queries executed when applying multiple where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following IQueryable where, with multiple evaluations, but I'm noticing that this resulted in 9 Queries getting executed against the server?  When in reality it should only be one?

```
var datafound = db.CustomersData
    .Where(x => x.EntryDate == eod.EntryDate);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eod.Type))
    datafound = datafound.Where(x => x.Type == eod.Type);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eod.LastName))
    datafound = datafound.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(eod.LastName));

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eod.Address))
    datafound = datafound.Where(x => x.Address.Contains(eod.Address));

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eod.BuildingName))
    datafound = datafound.Where(x => x.BuildingName.Contains(eod.BuildingName));

    .....
    .....


return datafound.ToList();
```

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion this resulted in 9 queries?

Comment: @TravisJ I agree - I can't see how this would execute 9 times, even if `CustomersData` wasn't an `IQueryable`. Can we see the queries that it is running?

Comment: Not with `IQueriable`. If yours "..." doesn't hide any additional logic. `ToList()` will "execute" (if I can say so) your actual query.

Comment: It should be one query, unless you add breakpoint to debug.

Comment: The ... is the same style of query builder.  i left out because it repeats the same thing

Comment: This is what I'm seeing as well when the above logic runs.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773386/glimpse-shows-duplicate-ef-queries

Answer (score 0):

The logic had a fillinViewBag Method before the .ToList() and inside fillinViewBag there were several evaluations for .sum .avg etc.

The fillinViewBag Method just needed the .Tolist() before and not after, that made the execution of the Query only 1 and fillinViewBag method just worked with the data from memory.

Thanks for the Quick Feedback.